# Set config.xml in Cordova to allow internet access

Tags: android, cordova, visual-studio-2015, cordova-plugins, visual-studio-cordova

I am using Visual Studio 2015 Community version.
I am creating app using Cordova for android mobiles that need an internet connection during access the app.

Everything running fine when I run my app in computer / laptop android emulator but when I install my app in mobile by running that app it disconnect the internet connection and without that my app can't run.

what to do?

I have came across these solutions but no one helps me to solve this problem.

[Link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29735597/cordova-5-0-0-android-app-can-not-connect-to-internet-using-android-4-0-0)

[Link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18447566/phonegap-android-internet-not-working)

[Link 3](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.0.0/cordova/connection/connection.html)

[Link 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27126194/android-permissions-in-cordova-4-0-config-xml)

Comment: Install cordova whitelist plugin

Comment: @shammon I am new to cordova can you please tell me how to install it or give me any link that tells the step by step process to install cordova plugin.

Comment: Open command prompt in your project folder and try this `cordova plugin add https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-whitelist.git`

Comment: I have installed by opening config.xml and go to plugins and Core I add Whitelist from Core. Is it right? If yes do I need to do any changes after adding plugin in my project?

Comment: How did you install it?did you use my commnad?

Comment: I have used your command but it does not recognized https and http so  I have installed using config.xml plugins.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94571/discussion-between-padhiyar-and-shammon).